# Error using yfinance library for python (read_csv() got an unexpected keyword argument 'on_bad_lines')

Tags: python, yfinance

Trying to download data from yahoo using the code

```
data = yfinance.download("AAPL", start="2023-01-01", end="2024-01-01")
```

I get

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Python37\lib\threading.py", line 865, in run
> self._target(*self._args, **self.*kwargs)   File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\multitasking_*init**.py", line 104, in
> _run_via_pool
> return callee(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\yfinance\multi.py", line 201, in
> _download_one_threaded
> keepna, timeout, many=True)   File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\yfinance\multi.py", line 218, in
> _download_one
> many=many)   File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\yfinance\base.py", line 156, in history
> tz = self._get_ticker_tz(debug_mode, proxy, timeout)   File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\yfinance\base.py", line 339, in
> _get_ticker_tz
> tkr_tz = utils.cache_lookup_tkr_tz(self.ticker)   File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\yfinance\utils.py", line 339, in
> cache_lookup_tkr_tz
> df = _pd.read_csv(fp, index_col="Ticker", on_bad_lines="skip") TypeError: read_csv() got an unexpected keyword argument
> 'on_bad_lines' Exception in thread Thread-12: Traceback (most recent
> call last):   File "C:\Python37\lib\threading.py", line 917, in
> _bootstrap_inner
> self.run()   File "C:\Python37\lib\threading.py", line 865, in run
> self._target(*self._args, **self.*kwargs)   File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\multitasking_*init**.py", line 104, in
> _run_via_pool
> return callee(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\yfinance\multi.py", line 201, in
> _download_one_threaded
> keepna, timeout, many=True)   File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\yfinance\multi.py", line 218, in
> _download_one
> many=many)   File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\yfinance\base.py", line 156, in history
> tz = self._get_ticker_tz(debug_mode, proxy, timeout)   File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\yfinance\base.py", line 339, in
> _get_ticker_tz
> tkr_tz = utils.cache_lookup_tkr_tz(self.ticker)   File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\yfinance\utils.py", line 339, in
> cache_lookup_tkr_tz
> df = _pd.read_csv(fp, index_col="Ticker", on_bad_lines="skip") TypeError: read_csv() got an unexpected keyword argument
> 'on_bad_lines'

I uninstalled the yfinance library and reinstalled it using `--no-cache-dir` but to no avail.
How do I fix this?

Comment: Are you using a very, very, very old version of pandas?  `on_bad_lines` was added in 1.3.0.

Comment: Working fine on `ubuntu 22.04` and `python 3.10.12` with yfinance `version 0.2.37`. If it's not working try creating a virtual environment and install yfinance in it and then run your code in that environment

Comment: Can you give complete traceback you got instead of an error line ?

Comment: I tried upgrading Pandas: pip install pandas --upgrade
Requirement already satisfied: pandas in c:\python37\lib\site-packages (1.1.5)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.15.4 in c:\python37\lib\site-packages (from pandas) (1.21.6)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.7.3 in c:\python37\lib\site-packages (from pandas) (2.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2017.2 in c:\python37\lib\site-packages (from pandas) (2021.1)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in c:\python37\lib\site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.7.3->pandas) (1.15.0)